# SQL Server 2000 daily backup, need advice

Tags: sql-server, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2000 daily backup, need advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/206300/sql-server-2000-daily-backup-need-advice)

HI all, in my company there is a SQL Server 2000, they ask me to make a backup plan for it, for example:

database #1:

1- they want a complete backup every 15 days (done).
2- they want a differencial backup every 1 day (done).
3- they want a transac log backup every 1 hour (done).
4- they want to keep the data for 1 month (?). this mean that they don't care about losing the information of the last month, they wat to keep the information of the current month

I was thinking to make a full backup (every 1 month) of the data base that overwrite existing media to solve this requirement, and here is my question: Am I doing the right about overwrite the existing media?? Or there is another way??, Need some advice here.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solutin ***sqlserveragent*** .  If  you cant  use basic  soft

Answer (score 0):

I would ask for clarification on point #4 from the company.  It is a bad idea to assume that they don't care about data over a month old.  If you make that assumption, the company wants data from over a month ago (which is almost guaranteed to happen), and you don't have it they will likely be upset.  Maybe what they meant was keep data up to a month old **available online** (not restore from tape), but again just ask - it will clear up the confusion.